# How to Build & Push Container from docker-compose.ci.build.yml File

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using ASP.NET Core and have used Visual Studio's [Add Docker Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker) feature to get started. This adds a `docker-compose.ci.build.yml` file to my project which is supposed to be used on a CI server.

How do I build my Docker image from a compose file and push the image to my private Docker registry. I've tried the `docker-compose build` command:

> docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.build.yml build

However this outputs an error:

> ci-build uses an image, skipping

Comment: Post your docker-compose file

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @zaitsman Not yet but here is the relevant GitHub issue https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/32. Microsoft does not seem very responsive though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a number of issues getting this to build initially. Fixes for me included updating Visual Studio 2017 to Update 4, updating the Visual Studio Tools for Docker extension, and updating/consolidating NuGet package references. In addition, in `docker-compose.ci.build.yml` I had to change the build image to `microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0-2.0-stretch` (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6178) for more details).

Assuming the docker-compose configurations are the same/similar to the default generated ones, try the following script:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.build.yml up
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
```

Bringing "up" `docker-compose.ci.build.yml` simply builds the project and then exits. The artifacts are published to the `obj/Docker/publish` folder. The "build" `docker-compose.yml` actually builds and tags the images using the artifacts from the `obj/Docker/publish` folder. I clean up at the end of my build script with the following:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.build.yml down
```

For reference/inspiration-- This is working on a custom Linux build server and producing four Docker images from a single solution-- two ASP.NET Core apps and two .NET Core apps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to build docker container without docker-compose.ci.build.yml. I used .Net Core tasks to build and publish .Net Core app to "obj/Docker/publish" folder as dockerfile expects and then used docker-compose task to build the container and push it to private container repository.